# python passing parameter modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cant seem to get this, I'm just not understanding how to pass parameters between modules. Granted this seems really simple to me but maybe I'm just not getting it, I am very new to python but do have programming experience.

```
def main():

  weight = input("Enter package weight: ")

  return weight

def CalcAndDisplayShipping(weight):

  UNDER_SIX = 1.1
  TWO_TO_SIX = 2.2
  SIX_TO_TEN = 3.7
  OVER_TEN = 3.8

  shipping = 0.0

  if weight > 10:
    shipping = weight * OVER_TEN
  elif weight > 6:
    shipping = weight * SIX_TO_TEN
  elif weight > 2:
    shipping = weight * TWO_TO_SIX
  else:
    shipping = weight * UNDER_SIX

  print ("Shipping Charge: $", shipping)


main(CalcAndDisplayShipping)
```

When I run this I get: Enter Package weight: (num)TypeError: unorderable types: function() > int()

Could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: I don't see any use of python modules anywhere in this code? Also, this code would give a totally different error, as main() is defined to accept no arguments, but you pass one (a callable).

Comment: The cause of the problem is that in Python 3 `input()` returns a string. This is not a problem in Python 2. You should indicate that you are using Python 3 so that these subtle differences can be considered. I have tagged the question with `python-3.x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is in python there is no need for a main. One other way to do it, that does the job is this.

Do you really need a main?

```
import os


def CalcAndDisplayShipping(weight):

   UNDER_SIX = 1.1
   TWO_TO_SIX = 2.2
   SIX_TO_TEN = 3.7
   OVER_TEN = 3.8

   shipping = 0.0

   if weight > 10:
      shipping = weight * OVER_TEN
   elif weight > 6:
      shipping = weight * SIX_TO_TEN
   elif weight > 2:
      shipping = weight * TWO_TO_SIX
   else:
      shipping = weight * UNDER_SIX

   print ("Shipping Charge: $", shipping)

weight = float(input("Enter package weight: "))

CalcAndDisplayShipping(weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you mean this:

```
CalcAndDisplayShipping(main())
```

This will call `main()` and pass its return value as an argument to `CalcAndDisplayShipping()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def CalcAndDisplayShipping(weight):

    UNDER_SIX = 1.1
    TWO_TO_SIX = 2.2
    SIX_TO_TEN = 3.7
    OVER_TEN = 3.8

    shipping = 0.0

    if weight > 10:
        shipping = weight * OVER_TEN
    elif weight > 6:
        shipping = weight * SIX_TO_TEN
    elif weight > 2:
       shipping = weight * TWO_TO_SIX
    else:
       shipping = weight * UNDER_SIX

    print ("Shipping Charge: $", shipping)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    weight = float(input("Enter package weight: "))
    CalcAndDisplayShipping(weight)
```

If you are running this script using python interpreter like 
python `script_name.py`, `__name__` variable value will be `'__main__'`.

If you are importing this module to some other modules `__name__` will not be `__main__` and it won't execute the main section.

So you can use this feature if you want to do anything while you are running this module as an individual script.

This 'if condition' only satisfies if you are running your module as an individual script.

Comment: if you are running this script as a individual script __name__ variable

Comment: If you are running this script using python interpreter like python script_name.py, __name__variable value will be '__main__'. If you are importing this module to some other modules __name__ will not be __main__ and it wan't execute the __main__ section. So you can use this feature if you want to do anything while you are running this module as an individual script.

Comment: I have deleted my comments, since you've now made them obsolete. Thanks!